# How to isolate only the first space in a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a foreign language to English dictionary that I'm trying to import into a sql database. This dictionary is in a text file and the lines look like this:

> field1 field2 [romanization] /definition 1/definition 2/definition 3/

I'm using regex in python to identify the delimiters. So far I've been able to isolate every delimiter except for the space in-between field 1 and field 2.

```
(?<=\S)\s\[|\]\s/(?=[A-Za-z])|/
#(?<=\S)\s\[  is the opening square bracket after field 2
#\]\s/(?=[A-Za-z]) is the closing square bracket after the romanization
#/ is the forward slashes in-between definitions.
#????????? is the space between field 1 and field two
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using a script that converts a text file into an sql databse, though to do this i need to tell the script what the delimiters in the text file are. One of the delimiters is the first space ie field1[RIGHT HERE]field2 though i dont know what to type in regex to identify this.

Comment: I want the regex query to match the first space in a line.

Comment: But if you're looking for the first space in a line, what good is it? If you know there's a space, the regex always returns a space, so why look for it in the first place?
Somehow I'm not getting you, sorry -.-

Comment: Sorry I'm awful at explaining. This is a line taken from termsql  that creates a row in a database by splitting it around delimiters     row = re.split(regex_delimiter,line.rstrip('\r\n').lstrip())

Comment: the first space is a dlimiter so i need a regex command to identify it

Comment: Does Python have the `\K` construct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Python supports the `\K` construct, this will work.
This construct is a poor mans version of a variable length lookbehind.

```
 # (?m)(?:^[^\s\[\]/]+\K\s|(?<=\S)\s\[|\]\s/(?=[A-Za-z])|/)

 (?m)
 (?:
      ^ [^\s\[\]/]+ 
      \K 
      \s 
   |  
      (?<= \S )
      \s \[
   |  
      \] \s /
      (?= [A-Za-z] )
   |  
      /
 )
```

Apparently, Python does not have this construct, but might support
variable length lookbehind's with their experimental *regex* module.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

```
 # (?m)(?:(?<=^[^\s\[\]/]+)\s|(?<=\S)\s\[|\]\s/(?=[A-Za-z])|/)

 (?m)
 (?:
      (?<= ^ [^\s\[\]/]+ )
      \s 
   |  
      (?<= \S )
      \s \[
   |  
      \] \s /
      (?= [A-Za-z] )
   |  
      /
 )
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, not the re library anyway. Thanks anyway though

Comment: Sorry, yeah it would with thier experimental regex module. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to vote this answer up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kZ7qL1/3), it isolates all fields and delimiters:

```
import re

preg = re.compile(r'^(?P<field1>\S+)(?P<delim1>\s+)'
                  r'(?P<field2>\S+)(?P<delim2>\s+)'
                  r'\[(?P<romanization>\S+)\](?P<delim3>\s+)'
                  r'/(?P<def1>[^/]+)/(?P<def2>[^/]+)/(?P<def3>[^/]+)')
lines = ['field1 field2 [romanization] /def 1/def 2/def 3/',
         'Foo Bar  [Foobar]\t/stuff/content/nonsense/']

for line in lines:
    m = preg.match(line)
    if m is not None:
        print(m.groupdict())
```

Your first delimiter, for example, would be in `m.group('delim1')`.

Comment: I should be able to edit the code so that using this method will work, thanks